# Delete Datalist row with multiple primary keys

Tags: asp.net

I have a datalist with a OnDeleteCommand="Delete_Command".

I want the delete a record with multiple primary Keys but I do not know how to access it from the Delete_Command event.

If I use DataKeyField I'm limited to only one key.
Any workarounds for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access all of the keys:

```
gridView.DataKeys[rowNum][dataKeyName]
```

where rowNum is e.RowIndex from the gridView_RowDeleting event handler, and dataKeyName is the key you want to get:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridView" runat="server" DataKeyNames="userid, id1, id2, id3" OnRowDeleting="gridView_RowDeleting">

protected void gridView_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
    gridView.DataKeys[e.RowIndex]["userid"]...
    gridView.DataKeys[e.RowIndex]["id1"]...
    gridView.DataKeys[e.RowIndex]["id2"]...
    gridView.DataKeys[e.RowIndex]["id3"]...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh, sorry, I missed it.

AFAIK there is no such a possibility by default. Maybe you can create a composite key from your primary keys, like

> Key1UnderscoreKey2UnderscoreKey3

and split it in the event handler. So this is a DIY multi-key handler for DataList :-)

Edit: The underscore got lost during format, it replaces with italic text. So instead of "underscore" word use real underscores