# DataKeys dataList

Tags: asp.net

This is my bare DataList definition :-

```
  <asp:DataList runat="server" ID="dtltrial" 
            ondeletecommand="dtltrial_DeleteCommand" DataKeyField="PhotoId" >

       </asp:DataList>
```

where PhotoId is my primary key of table and so i have given it as datakeyField. However i also want `AlbumId` along with DataKeyField. How do i specify it in DataKeyField and later on retrieve it in `ondeletecommand` event of DataList?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify:

```
DataKeyNames="PhotoId,AlbumId"
```

**Update:**

It looks like the **DataList doesn't allow you to specify multiple keys**, and then retreive them as normal. [From this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19436), the accepted answer deals with a `GridView`. Unfortunately the `DataList` doesn't function the same.

You'll likely have to create a unique identifier yourself at the datasource, or create a hybrid on a databinding event. For example, "PhotoId_AlbumId", which would turn into "837_7826". On the delete event, you'd then have to extract out the two IDs, separated by the underscore.

Consider creating a new single primary key on the datasource instead.